# How can I select all text in a div after focusing using a ref in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable, ref

In a nutshell, I'm trying to select all text after setting it to contentEditable = true and focusing, all using a ref. Ideally, I would do this using an onFocus event. I was unable to find any solutions online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `select()` like this-

```
<refField>.current.select()
```

You may want to add above line in `useEffect` and `contentEditable` as its dependency.

Comment: Ya I tried that, select() isn't a function on refs.